# How to define the width and id of an element created by .append()?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, append

I'm trying to create an `select` element that has `width="347px"` and `id="select-box-1"`, this element is created from `.append("select")`, I already tried to search about `.append()` but the explanation led me to an attempt that failed.

Failed Attempt:

```
.append("<select id='select-box-1' style='width: 347px'></select>")
```

Original part of my script that creates the `.append()`:

```
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
<script id="script-da-caixa-de-selecao-suspensa-1">
    function caixasuspensa1(error, data) {
      var select = d3.select("#caixa-suspensa-1")
        .append("select")
```

**Note: this function works with `D3.js`**

Full script in case to tests:

```
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
<script id="script-da-caixa-de-selecao-suspensa-1">
    function caixasuspensa1(error, data) {
      var select = d3.select("#caixa-suspensa-1")
        .append("select")
    
      select
        .on("change", function(d) {
          var value = d3.select(this).property("value");
          document.querySelector('#barra-de-texto-para-radar-1').value = value;
          document.getElementById('botao-do-radar-1').click();
        });
    
      select.selectAll("option")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
          .append("option")
          .attr("value", function (d) { return d.value; })
          .text(function (d) { return d.label; });
    }
    
    d3.csv("Lista_de_Jogos.csv", function(error, data){caixasuspensa1(error, data)});
</script>
```

Comment: You have some vanilla approaches in the answers, with d3 you can use: `d3.select("#caixa-suspensa-1").append("select").attr("id","select-box-1").style("width","347 px")`.

Comment: Hello my friend, your indication for ```d3``` worked here, the ```id``` was created, but the ```width``` not, would the error be in the form I'm trying to define with ```px``` at the end?

Comment: My apologies, I added a space where I shouldn't have: [eg](https://jsfiddle.net/m4gLyodq/1/)

Comment: Thank you very much, now I'm going to fight here to see how I can update this ```"select"``` every 60 seconds without having to delete the entire element and add a new one. Anyway, if you want, create a answer with ```d3.select("#caixa-suspensa-1").append("select").attr("id","select-box-1").style("width","347 px")``` so that I can mark it as my solution, as it perfectly fit my need!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In D3 selection.append() receives either a string representing the type of element (eg, "select", not a string representing the html of an element) or a function. The string you provide is not a tag, so it doesn't work.

D3's attr and style methods are intended to set both attributes such as `id` and styles such as `width`. You do this when you set the value of the options: `.attr("value",` - we can do the same with id:

```
.attr("id","select-box-1")`
```

And with width:

```
 .style("width","347px")
```

Which provides us with:

```js
var select = d3.select("body")
  .append("select")
  .attr("id","select-box")
  .style("width","347px");
  
select.selectAll(null)
  .data([1,2,3,4])
  .enter()
  .append("option")
  .text(d=>d)
  .attr("value",d=>d);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Alternatively, we could pass a function to .append which is a bit more fancy, but offers no tangible benefits in this case.

---

Based on the comment on updating, here's a quick demo using selection.join:

```js
var select = d3.select("body")
  .append("select")
  .attr("id","select-box")
  .style("width","347px");
  
var data = [1,2,3,4]
  
function update(data) {
  
  select.selectAll("option")
    .data(data)
    .join("option")
    .text(d=>d)
    .attr("value",d=>d);
    
}

// load initial data:
update(data);


// generate new data and pass to update();
d3.select("body")
  .append("button")
  .text("update options")
  .on("click", function() {
    var min = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
    var length = Math.round(Math.random() * 3 + 3)
    data = d3.range(length).map(d=>d+min);
    update(data);
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.0.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try appending to the `innerHTML`:

```js
document.body.innerHTML+="<select id='select-box-1' style='width: 347px'></select>";
```

Or use [`insertAdjacentHTML()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML):

```js
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", "<select id='select-box-1' style='width: 347px'></select>");
```

Comment: Hi mate, how are you? I tried to use it as instructed and it looked like this: ```.append(document.body.innerHTML+="<select id='select-box-1' style='width: 347px'></select>")```, but unfortunately the ```select``` was not created as append of ```#drop-box-1``` and the ```option``` data did not appear.

Comment: @BrondbyIF Remove the `.append`. Just: `document.body.innerHTML+="<select id='select-box-1' style='width: 347px'></select>"`

Answer (score 2):

> create an select element that has width="347px" and id="select-box-1"

- I guess the best way to do is creating a new element and use `setAttribute()` to style it and put its id:

```js
let select = document.createElement("select");

select.setAttribute("id", "select-box-1");
select.setAttribute("style", "width: 347px;");

document.body.append(select);
```

```html
<body></body>
```

---

- Alternatively:

```js
let select = document.createElement("select");

select.id = "select-box-1";
select.style.width = "347px";

document.body.append(select);
```

```html
<body></body>
```